# Hide logs not matching query in IDEA console, similar to Stackdriver

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

The Google Cloud console allows users to search for log messages and logs that are not matching the query are hidden and the user can run through only the matching logs.

Is there a way to get a similar functionality on IntelliJ IDEA? This would make combing through larger logs a lot easier.

Currently search for a string simply highlights it, without hiding log lines that don't match the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ's [GrepConsole](https://github.com/krasa/GrepConsole) offers something like this.

Although this plugin does not provide the user friendliness of Stackdriver's `right click > exclude / include` features, it can:

- Search the IntelliJ console
- Display only those lines which match your search
- Form searches from regexes

For example ...

Complete console content:

[image]

Use GrepConsole to find only those entries containing `"This"`:

[image]

Use GrepConsole to find only those entries containing `"FooTest"`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!